# Binding SSRS report to complex Business Layer Object

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I have a Business Layer class which has few properties as a List of object. The search method returns a List of objects. So the list returned contains, few members, which are list of object themselves.

Now, when I try to bind my SSRS report, the normal members are getting bound with the report elements, however, I am not able to bind report elements to the property of list items, which themself are list of objects. e.g.

A list item looks like this

Id
Name
Address
List

where Subjects is an object having properties {SubjectId, SubjectName, SubjectDescription}

I want a report as follows:

### Id                   Name                     Address                 Subjects

1                    A                        AddressA                Physics
                                                                      Maths

2                    B                        AddressB                Maths
                                                                      Chemistry
                                                                      Botany

3               C                  AddressC          Physics

Comment: How are you attempting to bind the report elements to the list?   Can you be more specific about the steps you are taking and what error you receive?

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to include some code and describe more precisely what you have and where you're stuck.  Editing your question also gets it fresh looks.